# How to echo the missing selector in a CasperJS onWaitTimeout event handler?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, wait, casperjs

I have many `casper.waitForSelector` parts in my script. Anyway I would like to know whenever it times out. Therefore I added:

```
casper.options.onWaitTimeout = function() {
    //how to echo Selector which timed out here
};
```

Furthermore I would like to echo the selector which timed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of [`onWaitTimeout`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#onwaittimeout) is:

```
onWaitTimeout(Integer timeout, Object details)
```

Which is sadly not correctly documented. The `details` object that is passed into the function contains a `selector` property that represents the selector. If it is an XPath selector, then you will need to get the `path` property of that.

```
casper.options.onWaitTimeout = function(timeout, details) {
    var selector = details.selector.type === 'xpath' ? 
            details.selector.path : details.selector;
    this.echo("Wait timed out after " + timeout + " msec with selector: " + selector);
};
```

Please note that this function will catch all wait timeouts and you will have to exit the script yourself if you so choose.

It's always a good idea to look at the source code: [1](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L2199) & [2](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L2100).